# I accidently signed up for HSA and paid the money back to the state I work for

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa

I accidently signed up for HSA and paid the money back to the state I work for. Yet my W-2 still reported $1798.37 in box 4 for HSA and I rcvd a 5498-SA form for $1194.12, the amount I paid back. I was told the W-2 would be amended (last year) - but it doesn't look like it was. I called my work and they told me to check with an accountant, but I'm using Turbo Tax. What do I need to do?